# Send SMS from arduino to Android App Using Twilio and Vice Versa

Tags: android, android-studio, twilio, twilio-api

I am building an app which intends to send data from an arduino uno to an android app and vice versa using twilio.

I know the best way to do this is by using a RESTFUL API, however, is there a way to send and receive SMS directly from the android app through twilio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could send an SMS from an Android app via Twilio, however it's not recommended. There is a [discussion on why this is an issue and how to work around it in this blog post by my colleague Marcos](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html). The key is this point:

> While Twilio is a REST API and theoretically you could make an HTTP
>   request to it directly, you would need to store your Twilio
>   credentials inside your app which poses a serious security issue. An
>   attacker could decompile the application, extract your credentials and
>   use your Twilio account for anything they liked.

So the best practice is to use a server to [send SMS messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) from your Android app.

Let me know if that helps at all.